# Why is electron complaining of unexpected token:

Tags: typescript, windows, electron, webstorm

I am following the JetBrains description of how to run electron with WebStorm on Windows (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/). This works perfectly with js but when using ts I receive an error ‘unexpected token :’. I am not currently doing my own transpilation as the walkthrough suggests that the electron cmd will handle that, however the error suggests it is not. Am I missing some steps?

package.json

```
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc main.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "electron": "^18.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "electron-packager": "^15.5.1",
    "intl-pluralrules": "^1.3.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The supposedly offending line is just

```
let mainWindow: Electron.CrossProcessExports.BrowserWindow | null;
```

Comment: Are you going to share the supposedly offending code?

Comment: Electron doesn't compile TS for you. I don't see how the walkthrough suggests that. (All it says is that since v1.6.9 a TS definition file is included so a compiler or IDE can detect mistakes. It even says "TypeScript [...] that **you** compile to JS".)

Comment: @CherryDT thanks for the clarification. I guess I was thrown by the fact that the article was tagged as typescript and then goes on to give a description of how to run/debug plain js :)